# can't access to joomla administrator panel

Tags: joomla

after reinstalling civicrm on joomla, I can't access the administrator panel because "Fatal DB error, exiting, seems like your schema does not have civicrm_setting table" - any idea? solutions? thank you...

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED - I think this is not exactly the right way but I've deleted the civicrm folders in administrator -> components, in components and in plugins -> user (on the server) and the tables in the database... now I can access the administrator panel